# Why can't we see what others have voted to close?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, vote-to-close, privacy

When I go to the `votes` tab on my profile, I can see what I have voted to close.

When I go to someone else's profile, I can't see the votes tab, meaning I can't see what they voted to close.

What's private about this info? I can see the people that voted to close a post, so why can't I see the posts people voted to close?

> **Note:** I'm not asking for this information to be shown. I'm asking *why* this is the case.

Answer (score -1):

Why not? There's no need for it. A lack of a feature doesn't need a justification, a feature does.

As far as elections go, you can already see their review history in the activity tab.

I guess there could be a case for mods being able to see close/delete vote histories, but I haven't come across a situation (yet) where I would need that.

Comment: I'm specifically thinking about election nominees.

Comment: @Undo the activity tab isn't enough for that? FWIW, the votes tab doesn't show _all_ close votes either, iirc (there's something about deleted votes that I don't understand).